# mvc run jwplayer when execute Ajax.ActionLink onsuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, video, jwplayer

I am doing an MVC 5 App, I want to show and .MP4 video with `JWplayer`.

When I show a Video `on ready` and `onclick` it works fine.

But I need to show a Video when user load a new Model. I use `Ajax.ActionLink` and define `UpdateTargetId` to the div that load MP4 Video. `OnSuccess` I define a function that load the new Video, but get an error...

Here is my code..

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("MediaPlayer").setup({
            file: "/Download/20170314/3_b@b.com_5_1.MP4",
            title: "My Cool Trailer"
        });

         function OnComplete(request, status) {
            loadVideo("/Download/20170314/test_1_1.MP4");
        }
        function loadVideo(myFile) 
             jwplayer('MediaPlayer').load([{
                 //'fileflash': 'Jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                 'file': '/Download/20170314/test_1_1.MP4',
                 //'id': 'playerID',
                 'width': '600',
                 'height': '450'
             }]);
             jwplayer().play();
         };

    </script>
```

[image]

It shows that when View load, it shows and `mp4` with a label "My cool Trailer"..

When I click on Button, It calls a function called `loadVideo`. It Works fine....

When I click `Load` `ActionLink`, it goes to controller. Never matter what is get back... It is display in `UserUpload` div. But get the following error.

[image]

Obviously something from jwplayer.js breaks when it goes to Controller and came back.

Any idea?